# Doubts about cartesian product existence.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, axioms

Why I can't to show that the cartesian product between two sets exists without replacement or power set axioms?

Comment: How do you define the Cartesian product? You can have many different ways of defining ordered pairs, and generally speaking Replacement is equivalent to the statement "Every way you can define an ordered pair will also let you define the Cartesian product".

Comment: @AsafKaragila For istance $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a unique empty set (Existence, Extensionality, Comprehension).

For any $x,y$ there is a unique $z=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}=(x,y)$ (Pairing, Extensionality).

For any $X,Y$ there exists $X\cup Y=\bigcup \{X,Y\}$ (Pairing, Union).

Let $g(x,y)$ be $(x\in X\land y\in Y).$

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be $(\;(g(x,y)\land z=(x,y))\lor ((\neg g(x,y)\land z=\emptyset)\;).$

Apply Replacement & Comprehension to $\forall x\in X\cup Y\;\forall y\in X\cup Y\;\exists! z\;(f(x,y,z)$ to obtain, for any $X,Y$ that $$\exists Z\;\forall z\;(z\in Z\iff \exists x\in X\cup Y\;\exists y\in X\cup Y\;(f(x,y,z)).$$ For such $Z$ we have, by Comprehension, the existence of $\{z\in Z: z\ne \emptyset\},$ which is $X\times Y.$

Comment: Thanks for your proof, it is quite original. But my question is how I can't to show that is impossible obtain the existence of cartesian product without replacement or power axiom.

Comment: Clearly I was careless in reading the Q.   BTW there are 2 different versions of Replacement in the books. One of them implicitly incorporates Comprehension into itself; the other doesn't. I dk how this affects the Q.